# Could not get unknown property 'anko_version' for object of type...?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, anko

I am trying to use Anko with my Android Kotlin Project. I have added the line to my dependencies / gradle module file as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

But I get the following error when trying to do a gradle sync:

> Error:(36, 0) Could not get unknown property 'anko_version' for object
>   of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>   Open File

How can I properly incorporate Anko in my project?

For reference, I am using Android Studio 2.0.

Comment: Just replace `$anko_version` with `0.10.1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `anko_version` in `ext` block above the `dependencies` block:

```
ext {
   anko_version = '0.10.1'
}
```

Another option, as  Naetmul suggested in the comments, is to replace the `$anko_version` with `0.10.1`

Answer (score 2):

You can define it in your project level build.gradle file.

[image]

**OR**

You can replace with current version which is **0.10.1** (on 1 Sep 2017)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it and it works great:

1. Open your `project gradle`.
2. Add a `ext` block within the `buildscript` block.
3. Add your versions properties.

[image]

Within your `app gradle`, set your versions like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

Don't use this

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

and don't use this

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```